# How to optimize code below by getting rid of redundant?

Tags: java

My code below is to calculate ProductFunction based on some values of Object Product. Method getProductFunctions in InternalProductMapper and ExternalProductMapper call functions in ProductFunctionCalculator to calcuate the value of ProductFunction. According to me its not possible to have a single function in ProductFunctionCalculator, because two different mappers call it. How can I optimize the code below? Also, If I have two functions, i am not sure what to name the other as both calculate function for two different mappers.

```
public class InternalProductMapper{
  public EnumSet<ProductFunction> getProductFunctions(Product p){
     return productFunctionCalculator.get(p);
  }
}

public class ExternalProductMapper{
 public EnumSet<ProductFunction> getProductFunctions(Product p){
     return p!=null ? productFunctionCalculator.calculate(p):
                       return EnumSet.of(Function.BUSINESS,Function.MARKET);
  }
}

public class ProductFunctionCalculator{
   public EnumSet<ProductFunction> calculate(Product p){
      if(p.brand() == "ABC" && p.id.equals("1") && p.value > 100){
          return EnumSet.of(Function.BUSINESS, Function.LOCAL);
      }
   }

    public EnumSet<ProductFunction> get(Product p){
       if(p != null && p.location.equals("NY")){
            return EnumSet.of(Function.BUSINESS);
       }
       return EnumSet.of(Function.BUSINESS, Function.MARKET);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are compilation errors in at least two of those methods.

Answer (score -1):

> "Also, If I have two functions, i am not sure what to name the other as both calculate function for two different mappers."

You can name one **calculateInternal** and the other **calculateExternal** or similar, unless I misunderstand what you mean to say.

You can also add an Identifier on your **Product** object, to ascertain if it is internal or external(Could be a new field, boolean/enum or otherwise). You would need to set the value of this field on initialization of the Product object, when you most probably know what kind of Product it is. This could allow for a new single method of calculating, because now your method would know how to handle the different scenarios(As you have this new 'type' field), possibly via an if-else statement such as:

```
//This should not be allowed if you can help it and you should try and get 
//rid of the scenario this comes in as null - just check it before calling this method 
if(product != null) {
  if(product.isInternal()) {
    //Internal product logic
   } else {
    //External product logic
  }
}
```

Comment: `product.isInternal() ? return x : return y;` is not valid Java.

Comment: Amended for simplicity, x and y were not supposed to be something valid